# Are eigenvalues (resp. unit eigenvectors) dependent continuously on elements $a_{ij}$ of a symmetric matrix $A$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, continuity

Let $A(t)=(a_{ij}(t)),~(t\in \mathbb R)$ is a symmetric matrix such that $a_{ij}(t)=a_{ji}(t)$ is a real-valued continuous function. Let $\lambda_1(t) \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_n(t)$ is all of the eigenvalues of $A(t)$.

1. show that each $\lambda_i(t)$ is continuous in $t$.

(Note: if $i=1$ or $n$, it may be easy thanks to the well-known relation $\lambda_\max = \max_{x\not= 0} \frac{x^T A x}{x^T x}$, but it becomes very hard for me even in the case $i=2$)

2. Moreover, for a given $i$, if $v_i(t)$ is the eigenvector corresponding
   $\lambda_i(t)$ with unit length in the standard eudlidean metric, is the function $t\mapsto v_i(t)\in \mathbb R^n$ continuous as
   well?
3. What if we assume $A(t)$ is skew-symmetric rather than symmetric?
4. What if we consider, in analogy, the smooth version of the same problems, replacing all "continuous" by "smooth"?

Comment: What do you mean by "smooth version" of the problem?

Comment: See https://www.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/509S07/eigenv5b.pdf

Comment: Remove the  catastrophic  condition $\lambda_1(t) \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_n(t)$.

Comment: The condition $\lambda_1\ge\cdots\ge\lambda_n$ gives some basic issues for points (3) and (4). For (3) consider $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & t \\ -t & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ whose eigenvalues are $ti$ and $-ti$ (who's the bigger one?); for (4) consider $$A(t)=\begin{pmatrix}t&0\\0&-t\end{pmatrix}$$ where $\lambda_1(t)=\lvert t\rvert,\ \lambda_2(t)=-\lvert t\rvert$.

Answer (score 1):

I outlines of my argument for key question 1) For 3) it is clear
that the $ \gamma_j (t) = - i \lambda_j$ are also continuous real
functions where $ i ^ 2 = -1 $.

My remarks **1)** The first point is that the
concept of continuous functions is local. So all my reasoning is
locally at one point.

**2)** The fact that $ \lambda $ are defined and real  ($ A
(t) $ symmetrical).

**3)** By a method analogue in the prove of Gershgorin
theorem (localization of the eigenvalues of matrix), and the fact
that the coefficients $ a_ {ij} $  of the matrix $A (t) $ are
continuous, we can assume that $ \lambda_{ij} $ are localy bounded
by the same constant.

**4)** Using some functions continuous proprieties   in a
neighborhood of a  given point follows:

**a)** if $ f $ is bounded and $ g $ continues,   then $ fg$
continues involves  $ f $ continuous

**b)** If $f$ and $g$ are defined and positive, then $f + g$
 continuous involves $f$ and $g$ continuous.

**c)** if $f$ well defined and
bounded with $f ^ 2$ continues, then $ f$ continues.

**5)** the coefficients $f_j(t)$ of the characteristic
polynomial of $A (t) $  are  continuous (because in the $ det (A
(t)) $ intervenes only algebraic operations on continuous
functions $  a_ {ij}$ that retain continues propriety.

**6)** Relations between roots $\Lambda_{i}$ and the
coefficients of the characteristic polynomial $ f_j$ of $ A (t) $
(more precisely the $  f_j$ are function symmetric polynomials in
the $ \lambda_i$).

A last remark  sorry for my English,  and why you suppose that the
functions $ \lambda_i(t)$ are ordered?.

Prove of key question: if $n-1$ of $\lambda_j(t)$ are continues,
then by relation $\sum \lambda_j=\pm f_{n-1}$ we tack the other.

if $n-2$ of $\lambda_j(t)$ are continues, suppose are
$\lambda_3,\lambda_4,\cdot\cdot\cdot,\lambda_n$ and we show that
$\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are continues. So the $det(A(t))$ and
remarque **a**) and **5**) we have $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$
continues. also by **5)** $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ is continue and so
$\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+2\lambda_1\lambda_2$ is continue, so
$\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2$ is continue so $\lambda_1^2$ and
$\lambda_2^2 $ are continues. By **c)**  we conclude that
$\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2 $ are continues.